# How to show active directory user in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list

I want to show all the user which are available on SharePoint  active directory and showing on SharePoint list.

How we can show the user in SP list? Is there any idea?

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this similar situation:

[Get Active Directory Users in SharePoint List](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f4cac439-6faa-4a42-a842-6c59a7f99d2a/how-to-get-active-directory-users-in-to-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

If it doesn't work, you can also use some other tools.

The following article details the specific steps:

[Synchronize Active Directory Users](https://www.simego.com/blog/2013/10/synchronise-active-directory-users-with-sharepoint-list)